# Simulate memory Warning Issue with Model ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, didreceivememorywarning

I have a tab bar application. Each tab contains navigation controller allowing the user to transition from one view to the other. Each view is being handled by a view controller and each view controller class has -didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Problem: When I use "Hardware > Simulate Memory Warning" option of iPhone Simulator in any model viewcontroller after after that if I want to dismiss that controller using -

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Then, viewDidLoad method is not called for the controller to which I have added that model view controller, and app crashes there.
Any idea, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hello everybody, i have solved this one, just i was missing a line and it cost me 3 hrs to check on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this will be because, in viewDidLoad method u r not taking care of all the released object.In simulate memory warning , we have to release all those object , which can be loaded in viewDidLoad.